# Connecting to a WebSocket PHP server (code 1006 "Abnormal Closure")

Tags: php, websocket

I cannot establish a connection with the PHP WebSocket server, client closes it with code 1006 "Abnormal Closure".

Client code:

> var host = "ws://example.com:1234/test/server.php";

Server Code (test/server.php):

> $host = 'tcp://example.com:1234';

1. I tried different WebSocket PHP libraries.
2. I tried different hosts ("127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0", "example.com").
3. `sudo netstat -plnt` shows that port is listened.
4. Appropriate TCP port is opened (firewall settings in ISPConfig 3).

But connection still not working. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which PHP WebSocket libraries have you tested?

Comment: 1. https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket
2. https://github.com/esromneb/phpwebsocket
3. https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets

Comment: Going to take a look at those libraries quick.. In the meanwhile, think you might find it helpful to read this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed

Comment: Also, I don't mean to pour you down with things to read up on, but I recently started using sockets (with PHP) myself, and this library (http://socketo.me/) had good documentation, and a nice community. I'd recommend you take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've read that SO post, it is very detailed, but not concrete enough to solve an issue.

Comment: Ratchet has good reputation, but has many dependencies and requires Composer to be installed. I would like to use another minimalistic solution.

Comment: Yeah I can completely understand that, but PHP was never designed with Web Sockets in mind, and when you want to force it to have, I'd highly recommend you use something that has a few dependencies, but ensures more stability. And composer is as easy to use as GIT :)

Comment: What if Ratchet will not work after all, too? :) May be it is server configuration issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52038/discussion-between-user3345621-and-topright-gamedev)

Comment: Ok! Thank you again, you are very responsive! I've answered there.

Comment: Actually, it's just not enough information to be helpful other than by wild guessing. Websockets definitively work… Does it already abort upon connection or shortly later? Does your PHP script abort?

Comment: @bwoebi, server returns 0 bytes. PHP script doesn't receive a request, so script cannot abort it.

Comment: @toprightgamedev then _what is your server_?

Comment: It's Apache/2.2.22 at Ubuntu (Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64).

Comment: Have you checked the Apache Log if your request at least hits Apache? If this is not the case, the problem may lie clientside.