# websockets disconnects on wildfly openshift

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I have web application deploy on WildFly Application Server 8.2.0.Final on Openshift.
My application serves websockets endpoint.

I connect to the websocket endpoint with my java (tyrus implementation) client application and after short period (few hours) connection is closed by server side. I receive close reason "Closed abnormally" and close reason code: "1006". 
Client does automatic reconnection and then **exactly every hour**  connection is again broken with mentioned close reason. 
Is this builtin mechanism working on openshift serverside? Some sort of cleaning mechanism?

I would like to have permanent websocket connection to server. 
Would buying openshift broze/silver support solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your browser, not in the server:

> Close Code `1006` is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.
>
> If your browser client reports close code `1006`, then you should be looking at the `websocket.onerror(evt)` event for details.

See this SO answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305172/212224