# websocket close error handling

Tags: sockets, error-handling, websocket

When establishing a web socket connection between client to server the connection can close unexpectedly for several reasons:

1. Inactivity on the TCP channel.
2. server issue which makes the connection to close.
3. Client crash or reload/ refresh.

**I am looking for the way of dealing with such situations or, at least, know they occurred.**

When reading about WebSocket close, I understood the WebSocket protocol support server initiated **pings pongs**  which can be used for the server to know if a client has crashed. (client initiated ping pong are not supported). - is it the best way to deal with client crash?

Also, I see in spec that on the client side we can listen to the onClose event and that there are several codes to understand why connection has been closed - 
When the server crashed is that onClose event is always called?

Answer (score 5):

Both server and clients can send pings, however there is no method in the Javascript API to send such control frames.

A common approach is to send protocol level pings from the server to client regularly. If the server does not get a pong frame in a given time, the server disconnects the client.

However, clients should also know if the server is unreachable or the connection is half open, so having an application level ping/pong (i.e.: some user data representing a ping or pong) would allow both server and client figure out if the other end is not reachable anymore. As before, the server can send pings and expect pongs in a given time, but also the client can expect to have pings in a given time or consider itself disconnected, and then try to reconnect again.

About closing reasons, worth to check : [getting the reason why websockets closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed)

If the server crashes and the connection remains half open, you will have to detect this situation yourself and call `.close()` on the WebSocket object, and then the `onclose` event will be called.

Comment: thanks for response! what do you mean by connection which remains half open?

Comment: For example that the other end dies and you are still waiting for a message. If you try to send something, the underlying TCP will detect that the connection is actually disconnected, otherwise you get no "close" event. http://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection

Comment: This answer reminds me of this suggestion (https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl/issues/67#issuecomment-391170978), which I might try for solving https://stackoverflow.com/q/55224041/470749