# What does Going away 1006 error mean in Python Websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, ws4py

I have established connection with the server and everything worked fine. After couple of days I noticed data is not being updated, checked the logs and saw this:

> Message: 'Closed down' Arguments: (1006, 'Going away')

From the documentation:

```
        Completes the websocket by calling the `closed`
        method either using the received closing code
        and reason, or when none was received, using
        the special `1006` code.
```

What may cause the problem? I think it may be either lost internet connection or the server went down for a moment (the server is from a third party, not ours). However, those are my wild guesses and if anyone could give me some directions how to handle this error I will be very thankful. I would like, ideally, to wait some time if needed and connect again.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed This link might be of some help.

Comment: In my case I am using Python, so I was thinking I may somehow get more information.