# WebSocket on Wildfly 10 not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, websocket, wildfly

I have a problem with WebSocket to work on Wildfly 10, every time that I try send a message from Wildfly to the browser the connection is closed showing an 1006 code.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/debugger")
public class SocketDebugger {
    @OnOpen
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        session.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Teste");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

This error does not occur if I open a WebSocket connection on a machine with Windows 7 or lower. Also on my machine with Windows 10, when I create a project using NodeJS Socket.IO communication works standard, this error happens with Java projects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed

Comment: I have seen this post.

Comment: Did you implement the `@OnError` method? Maybe you'll get some more details about the 1006 code.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, Kaspersky had a block to the WebSocket communication.