# Closing WebSocket connection in JavaScript - 1006 error code everytime

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, websocket

Why does my WebSocket connection always closes with 1006 error code, even when I use .close(1000) or .close(3000).

Interestingly, when using the WebSockets connection with Express.js and Express-ws, this does not happen, only when using our real API. Could it be something the server does? Isn't 1006 local only though?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I rather doubt we can help you without seeing your actual code that the error happens to, both client and server ends of the connection.  Questions of the nature: "Why does my code do X?" must include that actual code.

Comment: I've actually tried and used ws://echo.websocket.org and that one works fine so it's most likely a server issue. Will close the question.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305172/470749) says:

> Close Code 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.
>
> If your browser client reports close code 1006, then you should be looking at the `websocket.onerror(evt)` event for details.
>
> ...