# Reproduce websocket errorcode 1006 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, jetty

Anyone know if there is a way produce the close code 1006 in websockets consistently. I´m trying to reproduce this scenario in a javascript client.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 1006 is special in the WebSocket spec.

Read prior answer on [close code 1006 in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305172/775715).

That might help you understand what you are up against.