# Socket connection is not establishing on https through javascript

Tags: javascript, https, websocket

I have develop the chat feature for my website, on the non-ssl website, the connection is establishing to the server using javascript, but when i configure the ssl on the website, the socket is not connecting to the server, with the error in the browser console ERR_Connection establishment, with the error code 1006. Please help me out in this matter, here is the attached code of javascript.

```js
<script>
        var host = 'wss://{host_ip_here}:4242';
        var socket = null;
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var print = function (input) {
               var sender_user_image=document.getElementById('sender_profile_image').value;
               var sender_name=document.getElementById('sender_name').value;
                    $("#messages").append('<li class="right clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-right"><img src="'+sender_user_image+'" class="img-circle"></span><div class="chat-body clearfix"><div class="header"><strong class="primary-font">  ' + sender_name+'</strong>' +
                            '<small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Few Seconds Ago</small>' +
                      '</div>' +
                     '<p>'+input+'' +
                      '</p>' +
                      '</div></li>');
            return;
        };

    //Manges the keyup event
    $("#send_button").button().click(function(){

            var msg = input.value;
            if (!msg)
                return;
            try {
            var messages = document.getElementById('input').value;
            var conversation_id = document.getElementById('conversation_id').value;
            var receiver_id = document.getElementById('receiver_id').value;
            var user_id = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                      receiver_id :receiver_id,sender_id:user_id,conversation_id : conversation_id,message:messages}));
                input.value = '';
                input.focus();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
                print(msg);
            return;
    });

    try {
        socket = new WebSocket(host);
        //Manages the open event within your client code
        socket.onopen = function () {
            var user_id = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
            socket.send("user_id="+user_id);
            return;
        };
        //Manages the message event within your client code
        socket.onerror=function(res){
            console.error(res);
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (response) {

        var reply=JSON.parse(response.data);
        var replier_image=document.getElementById('receiver_image').value;
                $("#messages").append('<li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left"><img src="'+replier_image+'" class="img-circle"></span><div class="chat-body clearfix"><div class="header"><strong class="primary-font">'+reply.user_name+'</strong>' +
                        '<small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>'+reply.sent_time+'</small>' +
                  '</div>' +
                 '<p>'+reply.message+'</p>' +
                  '</div></li>');

            return;
        };
        //Manages the close event within your client code
        socket.onclose = function () {

            return;
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: are you using self certificates?

Comment: no, godaddy authorized certificates

Comment: have you verified that 4242 port is open?, if it works on normal http there is no reason to do not work on https.

Comment: i have checked, its running fine

Comment: Your code suggest you are creating a websocket on something like "wss:1.1.1.1:4242" ... Are you missing the // in "wss://1.1.1.1:4242" ?

Comment: No, its not. i had used the "//" like you said i have used "wss://1.1.1.1:4242", just missed up after removing the website ip. sorry for that. help will be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed

Comment: @robertklep, I have read all of the reasons for the abnormal code error i.e 1006, I dont know the problem behind this still.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers (to rule out browser specific settings, like plugins), different computers (to rule out firewall issue), different internet connections (to rule out internet service provider issues)?

Comment: @AndersKellerCarstensenm, Yes do. I have checked in other computers too. but the same issue.

Comment: Did you try posting the message against another secure websocket server, like [this](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)? If that works, then it must be your websocket server that is failing.

Comment: @AndersKellerCarstensen, I have checked on the website you have sent, its working fine and sending messages when i am using the ws, but now connecting and sending message when i am using the wss.