# How do I turn off the 60 second time limit for the Chrome Headless mode?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I'm developing something related to the Chrome Headless pattern, and I'm using Java, so I need to connect to the Chrome browser using Websocket.
The tool I use is Java-WebSocket. When I started Chrome with the command line, and then connected to Chrome with websocket, it worked.

`chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222`


`ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/4477eb1d-b1e2-4163-8250-0b3f93c0ea14`


But after a full 60s, the connection is disconnected and the feedback code is 1006, which looks like the browser is actively disconnecting.
What I want to know is how to turn off this auto disconnect, or to extend the automatic shutdown time.
Thanks.

Comment: Based on what I read 1006 means closing without a closing frame. If that was true it was not really closed by chrome. "It is designated for use in
      applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
      connection was closed abnormally"

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed-with-close-code-1006