# WebSocket does not connect to a specific host until Chromium is restarted

Tags: google-chrome, browser, websocket, microsoft-edge, chromium

we are trying to debug an issue with Chromium (happens in Chrome, Edge, Brave), where it sometimes gets to a state where it does not open a WebSocket to a specific host.

We can see in console logs that it is trying to open the socket, but it never opens the connection. It fails with 1006 error. The same happens in new tabs and in new windows. The behaviour disappears after the browser is restarted or when an incognito tab is used.

There are no HTTP upgrade requests on the server and also the connection does not show up as WebSocket in chrome dev tools. We do not have much else to go on. Any suggestions on what we could try to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to test the web socket with the MS Edge (chromium) Version 83.0.478.58 and Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116

In my test, both the Chromium browser works well without 1006 error.

Here is the test code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

  </script>
<body>
  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[Web socket echo test](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

Try to check the security settings of the browsers and also confirm that you are trying to connect using a secure connection.

I found that 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.

I suggest you can check **WebSocket.onerror(evt)** to get more details about the error.

Helpful thread link:

[getting the reason why WebSockets closed with close code 1006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed-with-close-code-1006#:%7E:text=Close%20Code%201006%20is%20a,(evt)%20event%20for%20details.)

If there is more information then you can try to provide us that may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I observed exactly the same symptom (not sure about the error code) in Brave (but not in Chrome) during 2020 ... it was a constant issue... but since then it didn't happen almost at all since JAN 2021... except last week (in APR 2021) it happened again (in Brave).

Did anyone else notice the issue still being present from time to time? Or maybe it's a new bug, similar but more rare...

Exactly the same behaviour, socket doesn't reconnect except in incognito or after browser restart.

Answer (score 0):

We have been facing this exact issue where Websocket's upgrade requests never reach the server even though the network inspect tab shows that the request has been fired. No amount of refreshing or new tabs help until we switch over to Chrome. The issue is intermittent and has become impossible to debug but nonetheless our users keep reporting infinite loading bars due to the un-connected websocket.

I went through capturing network logs using `chrome://net-exports` and viewing it on the [net-export viewer](https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/) and the only time I could capture the logs for the issue, I noticed the browser only trying an IPv6 address and not the IPv4 address. (when our servers don't even have one)

Would it be prudent to engage Brave or Chromium team in this? Anyone ever found concrete repro steps for this?