# Websockets to localhost fails in chromium based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, microsoft-edge, django-channels

I'm trying to build a chat website that uses `vue.js` as the frontend and `django` as the backend. It works fine in `Firefox` but in `MS edge` and `Google Chrome`, Websocket is failing. I get this message in the browser console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/' failed
```

I use `django-channels` so in the python console it prints

```
WebSocket CONNECT /inbox/ [127.0.0.1:4965]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /inbox/ [127.0.0.1:4965]
```

When I print out the error code I get `1006`

> Close Code 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed
> abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation.

**My WebSocket code**

```
new WebSocket(url, authToken) // I use sec-websocket-protocol to transfer the authentication token
```

What am I doing wrong or is it a problem with the browser?

### ***-- Updated***

```
new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/", "authtoken");
```

So, I'm sending the authentication token in the second Websocket protocol and authenticating the user in the backend using middleware.
When I remove that protocol and accept unauthenticated users in the backend ->

```
new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/");
```

-> the WebSocket connects just fine. The problem is when sending the second Websocket protocol.

Comment: Which version of OS, Edge and Chrome are you using? Could you please use [`WebSocket.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onerror) to check the error details? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed-with-close-code-1006/19305172#19305172), code 1006 is a low level error with WebSocket itself which is in your code and implementation.

Comment: My os is `Windows 10 Pro OS build 19042.1288` and Edge browser version is `96.0.1054.43` (latest). I tried printing the error with `WebSocket.onerror` but it doesn't give much information. @YuZhou

Comment: I made a simple sample using [NodeJS WebSocket server ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-and-receiving-text-data), and it works well in Edge and Chrome with localhost. I think the issue might be related to django-channels. You can refer to [this thread](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1407) to see if it helps. Besides, does your domain use `http` or `https`?

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for the sample. My domain uses `http`.

Comment: If you're using the simple NodeJS WebSocket sample, will it work in Edge and Chrome? Does localhost domain work well in Edge and Chrome? It's hard to find the issue without a reproducible sample. If possible, you can provide the steps and a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @YuZhou I found the cause of the failure. Please check out the update.

Comment: @YuZhou I found the answer, check below. Thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added 'Token' as a subprotocol to the WebSocket and authToken along with it. Then in the backend, I accepted it with the same subprotocol name:

**My Websocket**

```
new WebSocket(url, ["Token", authToken]) // Sending 'Token' and authToken as subprotocols
```

**Token Auth Middleware**

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


@sync_to_async
def get_user(headers):
    try:
        token_key = headers[b"sec-websocket-protocol"].decode().split(', ')[1]
        token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)

        return token.user
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        return AnonymousUser()


class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        headers = dict(scope["headers"])

        if b"sec-websocket-protocol" in headers:
            scope['user'] = await get_user(headers)

        return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
```

**Consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class Consumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope['user']
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            self.room_name = await self.get_user_id(self.user)
            self.room_group_name = self.room_name

            await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
            await self.accept('Token')  # Here I'm giving a subprotocol to the self.accept function

        else:
            await self.close()
```