# My Blazor server app freezes with Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given) How to define root cause and fix the Error?

Tags: c#, websocket, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

I have a Blazor server side app where my screen freezed on executing a specific code. As I inspected on the Browser side I found the Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given). (Both on Chrome and Firefox)

This error I am getting the first time, after I executed following code on the related razor cs page: The client calls the method "ReadVariables" on button click. If the method is called first time after opening the page (once=true), the function AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_LoadGUD is executed, afterwards the function "AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_GetNCKDataRWByBTSSItem". In this case the method gives its outputs correctly,everything fine.

But if the same method is called the second time, the AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_LoadGUD is not executed, just the AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_GetNCKDataRWByBTSSItem. As you see I pass the output root_handle from the first function over the variable root_handle_2 to the second function.
Exactly on executing the line abc: (last line) the screen is freezing.

I don't know if the error is related to this point, but the worst thing is I cannot find the root cause.

```
public AGL4.NckNodeHandle root_handle_2 ;
public bool once = true;
    public void ReadVariables(int p_conn_nr)        
    {            
        int res = AGL4.AGL40_SUCCESS;
        if (once == true)
        {
            AGL4.NckNodeHandle root_handle = new AGL4.NckNodeHandle();
            res = AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_LoadGUD(p_conn_nr, ref root_handle);
            root_handle_2 = root_handle;
            once = false;   
        }          

        int variables_count = TagService.GUD_VAR_names.Count;
        //prepare list of variables to read
        AGL4.NckDataRW[] data_rws = new AGL4.NckDataRW[variables_count];
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(error_path))

        for (int i = 0; i < variables_count; ++i)
        {
            data_rws[i] = new AGL4.NckDataRW();                
            string variable = TagService.GUD_VAR_names[i];
            int error_position = 0;
       abc: res = AGL4.NCK_Symbolic_GetNCKDataRWByBTSSItem(root_handle_2, variable, ref data_rws[i], ref error_position); // when once=false (at the second execution of the method) exactly at this point the screen is freezing and I get this error. I get no error on code side.

        }
    }
```

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157/getting-the-reason-why-websockets-closed-with-close-code-1006?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Yes  I have read this entry. But what I cannot understand: Is this a User interface side Error, or is the root cause a failure in my code. I couldn't understand this from the browser detail explanation. The log is just giving java script related explanations

Comment: It means the connection did not complete which can happen for lots of different reasons.  The link for Joakim Erdfelt says you can get more info using : websocket.onerror(evt) event for details.