# Websocket connection on GCP breaks after ca. 90 seconds despite ping-pong

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-load-balancer

I'm experiencing problems with a websocket connection in a JavaScript web application. I'm using the native JavaScript `WebSocket` in both client and server (Node.js).

Everything seems to work locally but as soon as I connect to my remote server on GCP, it fails. After ca 60-90 seconds, the connection breaks with error code `1006`.

I don't get any ouput on `webSocket.onerror`, but `webSocket.onclose` gets triggered.

Ping-pong between client and server work every 10 seconds (as they should). I can see them in the Firefox dev console.

My suspicion is that GCP load balancer settings are somehow wrong. I found some vaguely related questions but nothing regarding my exact problem.

I am, unfortunately, forced to administer GCP via its GUI (web interface), so [this article](https://medium.com/johnjjung/how-to-use-gcp-loadbalancer-with-websockets-on-kubernetes-using-services-ingresses-and-backend-16a5565e4702) didn't help much either since I could not find the `timeoutSec` option mentioned there in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official google documentation on load balancers

> The timeout for a WebSocket connection depends on the configurable
> backend service timeout of the load balancer, which is 30 seconds by
> default. This timeout applies to WebSocket connections regardless of
> whether they are in use.

There are multiple ways for modifying the timeout value. In the article which you are following they are modifying the timeout value of the backend by passing that parameter in the headers. Since you use a GUI based one while creating a load balancer, go to the backend configuration and select create a backend service. Here you will be able to see a few settings for defining your endpoint and for setting the timeout value. Select the endpoint that is most suitable for your case.

Go through the below references for more information on timeout settings and which load balancer supports the websocket protocol.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#timeout-bes
[2] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_support

**Update:**

As mentioned in this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304157) by `Joakim Erdfelt`, **Error 1006** points to a low level issue related to your code and implementation. It is mainly caused because the browser is not able to reach your remote websocket server or when your websocket connection is getting closed abnormally. Check the websocket logs for more information on the error, check for any misconfigurations in websocket security spec and also check for any misplaced close connection methods in your code.

If possible provide your websocket code, error messages and firewall rules as it will be useful for providing a more detailed solution.