# Websockets works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

I have implemented websockets with authentication in Spring Boot by passing my bearer token within the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header as "Authorization, ". This is performed in my React frontend using the `react-use-websocket` package:

```
const {lastMessage, readyState} = useWebSocket(socketUrl, {
            protocols: ["Authorization", accessToken],
            share: true,
            retryOnError: true,
            shouldReconnect: (e) => true,
            reconnectInterval: 4,
            reconnectAttempts: 2,
            onError: (e) => {
                console.error('Error in websocket', e)
            }
        },
        Boolean(accessToken)
    );
```

It works properly in firefox as well as Insomnia (postman alternative). However, when I access my frontend in chrome, the connection immediately closes. I've stepped through the spring boot code and it's not receiving any messages from the client immediately after establishing the connection, so it just closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Spring Boot was not "accepting" the subprotocol by returning the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header with a value of "Authorization". Many thanks to this answer that helped me figure it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080916/6477292

To incorporate it in my application, I created a custom interceptor:

```
public class WebSocketSubProtocolInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        // Get the value of the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header
        List<String> protocols = request.getHeaders().get("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol");
        if (protocols != null) {
            for (String protocol : protocols) {
                // Check if the protocol contains "Authorization"
                if (protocol != null && protocol.contains("Authorization")) {
                    // Add the desired subprotocol to the response
                    response.getHeaders().add("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "Authorization");
                    break; // No need to continue searching
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
        // No action needed after the handshake
    }
}
```

And then added it to my WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private final Map<String, List<WebSocketSession>> sessions = new HashMap<>();
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean("sessions")
    public Map<String, List<WebSocketSession>> getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addHandler(new CustomWebSocketHandler(sessions, objectMapper), "/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .addInterceptors(new WebSocketSubProtocolInterceptor());
    }
}
```